# Schedule Computer to Shutdown and Turn on

Tags: shutdown, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

I have a small computer running Windows Server 2012 for storing files for remote access during the day.  At night, the machine is not needed.

Ideally, I'd like the machine to do the following:

- Monday - Friday: Turn on @ 8AM
- Sunday - Thursday: Turn off @ 11PM

I know I'll need to add some scheduled tasks, but I'm having issues finding the best implementation of what those tasks need to do.  What command specifically would I need to use to completely shut down, and to start up? Or is that piece not possible (and instead would need to be set to 'sleep'?)

Comment: Once the computer is shut down, that is it, its shut down. It won't be able to turn on via the OS. Sleep is your best option for this.

Comment: so this is probably my best bet? http://www.groovypost.com/howto/schedule-wake-sleep-windows-automatically/

Comment: That would be it, a scheduled sleep/wake cycle using task scheduler

Answer (score 3):

To automatically start your computer up at a specific time of day, you'll actually need to edit your BIOS settings. To do this:

Boot up your computer and enter your BIOS setup. Usually this involves pressing the Delete key as your computer boots 
(your computer should say 'Press DEL to Enter Setup' or something similar as you turn it on).

Navigate to the Power Options. If your BIOS supports it, there should be a function for automatically starting up your computer at a certain time of day. Mine was called "Resume by Alarm", but yours might be called something different.

Enable that setting and set the time you want your computer to start every day. Save and Exit the BIOS, and your computer should follow that schedule from now on.

You probably shut down your computer when you're done using it at the end of the day, but if not, you can set it to shut itself down on a schedule. This is easy to do with Windows Task Scheduler:

1. Hit the Start menu and type in "task scheduler". Open up Task
   Scheduler from your results.
2. In the right pane, hit Create Task. Give it a name, and under the
   General tab, check "Run with highest privileges". Also check "Run
   whether user is logged on or not", if you ever leave your computer
   logged out.
3. Head to the Settings tab and check "Stop the task if it runs
   longer than" and set it to "1 hour". This won't stop your computer
   from sleeping, but will stop your computer from thinking a task is
   still running.
4. Head to the Actions tab, hit New, and choose
   "Start a Program" as your action. Set the Program to `shutdown` and
   the arguments to `-s`
5. Lastly, head to the Triggers tab and click New. Change the schedule to fit whatever you want (say, Daily at 12:00AM), and hit
   OK. Hit OK again at the next window and your task should be saved in
   Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Check your BIOS.  Some BIOSs have power scheduling ability to enable startups and shutdowns.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively if your BIOS does not support this, you could also use the Wake on LAN feature which most servers have support for. You can use setup a schedule to run a tool such as http://www.solarwinds.com/free-tools/wake-on-lan or https://wakeonlanx.com/