# How to shut down and start up Debian server on a preset schedule?

Tags: debian, scheduled-tasks, cron, suspend, poweroff

I have a basic home server running Debian 11, which I am using to self-host a few things. I would like to set it up, so that it does not run during the night. Basically, I am doing this out of noise and power management considerations.

I have considered sending it to suspend or hibernate mode and then awakening it. However, I am unsure whether this is a good way to go about it. I have also considered turning it off, but I am unsure how I can awaken it from that state (perhaps BIOS?)

Hence, my question is what is the most efficient and simple way to accomplish this. In addition, if I do go via suspend or hybernate route, how can I do it on a schedule?

Comment: Seems like the only solution would be a BIOS setting if you r BIOS supports it. Look at [this answer here](https://superuser.com/a/630011/167207). The question is about Windows but all of the answers mention BIOS explicitly.

Comment: It makes sense that an OS that isn't running can't change powerstate, so yes, firmware is the only thing that could start up a powered-down PC for you on a schedule.

Comment: The above comments seem to miss an possible orkaround to the startup issue -if BIOS cant do it - a $10 wall timer. You can use crontab to shut it down.  Another possibility if you have other devices that can trigger it is WOL (wake on lan).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a combo of both the wall timer and WOL would be required unless you did somthing to the power button pins to make it always power on when it has power. otherwise just providing electricity won't turn the system on. you could probably set the timer, and after it turns on, send a WOL magic packet though.

Answer (score 1):

For changing the state of the machine while it is on, cron jobs will do the trick. For bringing the machine back up at a scheduled time, you'll need a separate device for that. Wake-on-LAN is a useful way to do this, assuming the machine's BIOS/EFI supports it. Some routers have configuration options for scheduling Wake-on-LAN to particular hosts at particular times. Another option is a small device that's always on and can push the WOL packets to the machine at a scheduled time, like your phone.

I poked around for an Android app that could send WOL packets, and found this one:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitklog.wolon&hl=en_US&gl=US

> Schedule automatic trigger of Wake on LAN packets, single time or recurrent (premimum feature)

However, it looks like you'll have to pay for the app as that bit is a premium feature.